# (CLOSED)Java serialization isn't working

Tags: java, serialization

I'm writing a Bukkit plugin that requires a bit of data persistence. Here's the code that I made to save an ArrayList of Projects to the file.

```
private ArrayList<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>;
private String filename = "plugins\\ProjectManager\\projects.cfg";


try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(projects);
    oos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    getLogger().severe("Unable to save projects to file. Data may have been lost.");
}
```

where

```
public class Project implements Serializable {...}
```

It will create the file, but nothing will be saved to it. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

---

Ok I'm unofficially closing this. It will be impossible to save it this way because of other dependencies with classes that are not serializable. Thanks for all of your help though.

Comment: It would be great if you log the Exception stacktrace in the `catch` block of your code.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. I'm not sure on what happens when you close., but try to explicitly call `flush()`.

Comment: Probably some sub component(s) of Project isn't serializable,  the error message will say though

Comment: Are there instances of different classes in Projects? Do they implement Serializable?

Comment: The code doesn't compile because it requires Bukkit as a library. But the flush() might do the trick.

Comment: The code doesn't compile since you can't mark variables as `private` or the code in your `try-catch` block is outside a method. Apart from those minor things, you're still blind to **the real problem** by not logging the exception stacktrace. Without it, we can just guess the problems you may have in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in code or errors you are not showing us.  This example works

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] ignored) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String filename = "config.data";

        List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
        projects.add(new Project());
        projects.add(new Project());
        projects.add(new Project());

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(projects);
        oos.close();

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        List<Project> projects2 = (List<Project>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        System.out.println("There was " + projects2.size() + " projects saved");
    }

    static class Project implements Serializable {

    }
}
```

prints

```
There was 3 projects saved
```